# How to generate a random string in a profile alias?

Tags: shell, quoting, alias, random

I have an alias in my server's `/etc/profile` which generates a random directory on command, like this:

```
alias rdir="mkdir -p ./`cat /dev/random | tr -cd 'a-z0-9' | head -c 8`/"
```

But it turns out this generates always the same string (in this case: directory). I figured out already this seems to be related to `source`'ing the profile file and only generates a new random string after I call `source /etc/profile`.

Now, I wonder, how do I generate a random string in an alias which always changes when I call the alias, like in this example: `rdir`? (Without re-`source`-ing?)

Comment: You also want to use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random`.

Comment: Why not simply use `mktemp --tmpdir=. -d XXXXXXXX` ? It would even check against existing folders an make sure it is a new directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes:

```
alias rdir='mkdir -p ./$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 'a-z0-9' | head -c 8)/'
```

Now, the statement is evaluated every time the alias is called. With double quotes the statement is evaluated, when defining the alias, therefore static.

Also a simpler solution to create a random directory inside the current working directory would be to use `mktemp`:

```
alias rdir='mktemp -d --tmpdir=./'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `pwgen` instead of `cat`ing and filtering `/dev/random`:

```
alias mkranddir='mkdir $(pwgen -s 8 1)'
```

Comment: `pwgen` is rarely installed on a default system.